# VMWare Memory Clear

Tags: memory-management, vmware-workstation

I have installed a VMWare 7.1 workstation for ubuntu 12.01. After using vmware for a month the folder contains too many of .vmdk files. Its costing the partition memory low.

1) How to free the memory that occupied by the vmware temporary memory.
2) What can i do to the .VMDK files - too many files are there is in the source path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Go to the snapshot manager and delete the old snap shot. It will give some free memory space
2)Go to the Setting windows and choose snapshot and set the snap shot setting when power off.